# How to generate a pre-patched version of Magento 1 SUPEE patch?

Tags: magento-1, patches, supee-11219, supee-11155

Some people like [Meetanshi](https://meetanshi.com/blog/install-magento-supee-11219/) has pre-patched version of Magento 1 SUPEEs. How they generate those files?

This is very useful for people (Like me) who are not able to apply patches via SSH from .sh files.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I am not sure How they do but You Or anyone can do it by following way.

1. Apply required patch by SSH
2. Once a patch is applied successfully, an entry is made in

   > app/etc/applied.patches.list
3. Look into `applied.patches.list` file, it will give you all the modified file by particular patch like :

[image]
5. Just copy those files in structured folder and Your pre-patched version is ready

Hope above will help!

Comment: This question is not about how to apply a Magento patch, it's about how to generate a pre-patched version. In some specific cases, it's not possible to do it that way. For example, on a non-fresh core Magento installation or projects with no ssh access.

Comment: correct! Answer also not about to apply patch. it is about how you can prepare pre-patch files and other can directly upload!